# Task was destroyed but it is pending! after /stop

Tags: python-3.x, rasa, rasa-nlu

i am learning rasa with python 3.8.10

The problem I am having is the following warning:

task: <Task pending name='Task-53' coro=<ctrlc_workaround_for_windows..stay_active() running at lib\site-packages\sanic\compat.py:79> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[<TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001CAD33C4CA0>()]>>

…with the following code:

import asyncio
import os
import signal

from sys import argv

from multidict import CIMultiDict  # type: ignore

OS_IS_WINDOWS = os.name == "nt"
UVLOOP_INSTALLED = False

try:
import uvloop  # type: ignore # noqa

```
UVLOOP_INSTALLED = True
```

except ImportError:
pass

def enable_windows_color_support():
import ctypes

```
kernel = ctypes.windll.kernel32
kernel.SetConsoleMode(kernel.GetStdHandle(-11), 7)
```

class Header(CIMultiDict):
"""
Container used for both request and response headers. It is a subclass of
`CIMultiDict <https://multidict.readthedocs.io/en/stable/multidict.html#cimultidictproxy>`_.

```
It allows for multiple values for a single key in keeping with the HTTP
spec. Also, all keys are *case in-sensitive*.

Please checkout `the MultiDict documentation
<https://multidict.readthedocs.io/en/stable/multidict.html#multidict>`_
for more details about how to use the object. In general, it should work
very similar to a regular dictionary.
"""

def get_all(self, key: str):
    """
    Convenience method mapped to ``getall()``.
    """
    return self.getall(key, default=[])
```

use_trio = argv[0].endswith("hypercorn") and "trio" in argv

if use_trio:  # pragma: no cover
import trio  # type: ignore

```
def stat_async(path):
    return trio.Path(path).stat()

open_async = trio.open_file
CancelledErrors = tuple([asyncio.CancelledError, trio.Cancelled])
```

else:
from aiofiles import open as aio_open  # type: ignore
from aiofiles.os import stat as stat_async  # type: ignore  # noqa: F401

```
async def open_async(file, mode="r", **kwargs):
    return aio_open(file, mode, **kwargs)

CancelledErrors = tuple([asyncio.CancelledError])
```

def ctrlc_workaround_for_windows(app):
async def stay_active(app):
"""Asyncio wakeups to allow receiving SIGINT in Python"""
while not die:
# If someone else stopped the app, just exit
if app.is_stopping:
return
# Windows Python blocks signal handlers while the event loop is
# waiting for I/O. Frequent wakeups keep interrupts flowing.
await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
# Can't be called from signal handler, so call it from here
app.stop()

```
def ctrlc_handler(sig, frame):
    nonlocal die
    if die:
        raise KeyboardInterrupt("Non-graceful Ctrl+C")
    die = True

die = False
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, ctrlc_handler)
app.add_task(stay_active)
```

i tried many way but i don't know how to fix

Please help me. Thanks